# How can i create a parser according to given grammar and check given input code is correct or not according to grammar?

Tags: c#, parsing

I want to create parser which will validate the syntax of program .You only need to consider the program syntax that can be generated from the grammar given below:
I have some grammar here.Check code line by line and output show this line is correct or not correct according to rule mention in program.How can i do this in c# asp.net. Please suggest me some links or provided materials or examples which may help me out..Thanks I don't know how can i do it.please help me.Thanks

Comment: Sorry but this both way too broad and off topic for SO. Google will help you netter..

Comment: Use a parser framework or write your own.

Comment: I try google but i can't found specific and related info.

Comment: It's not broad question,its just simple check the given program file according to grammar syntax

Comment: _I try google_ Try harder! Also read the [SO help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @TaW how can i search on google?I mean how can i search on this topic?

Comment: One good idea is to get the spelling right..: [c# grammar parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+grammar+parser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=q7iXVoznHMeqPs6qrdAJ)

Comment: Check out Irony.Net here: http://irony.codeplex.com/